# Connect CBPeripheral so that macOS MIDI Studio recognises the connection

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, coremidi

This is probably in a book but I don't know which.
I'm trying to connect a BLE MIDI `CBPeripheral` so that it becomes connected on MIDI Studio, i.e. usable as a MIDI source/sink by all the apps in the system. Although I get the indication that it is connected, it doesn't appear so in MIDI Studio or other apps. I know it's possible because Korg's Bluetooth MIDI Connect is able to do it. But it does seem to open the system's 'Bluetooth Configuration' window, so maybe there's no programmatic way of doing it.

- I'm creating a `CBCentralManager` and keeping a reference to it;
- When state is `poweredOn` I do a `scanForPeripherals`;
- When I get a `didDiscover:CBPeripheral`, I keep the reference to the `CBPeripheral` and call `central.connect(peripheral...)`;
- I get a `didConnect:CBPeripheral` and keep my app running, but it doesn't appear as connected to anyone else.

I know 'connected' means connected to my app. But I'd really like to have it available for others.
If this is a purposefully Apple-designed limitation, does anyone know what the purpose is?
If not, is there some CoreMIDI API I can use?

Comment: Connected means that you should see the peripheral listed in the Bluetooth section of the device settings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but the [apple guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/audio-midi-setup/set-up-bluetooth-midi-devices-ams33f013765/mac) gives you a hint on how to connect a BLE MIDI device to your Mac:

> 1. In the Audio MIDI Setup app  on your Mac, choose Window > Show MIDI
>    Studio.
> 2. In the MIDI Studio window, click the Configure Bluetooth button  in
>    the toolbar.
> 3. Set your Bluetooth MIDI peripheral in pairing mode.
> 4. Select the peripheral in the list of devices, then click Connect.

There is no need for custom coding. It should be possible for multiple apps to use the same BLE device, but the apps need to connect to it. BLE devices usually don't show up in the system settings but this might be different for MIDI devices.

Comment: That is how to do it via the UI. It's no fun to do it every single time you want to connect a specific device, hence the desire to be able to do it in a more streamlined way, preferably automatically. If the UI had a 'this device should connect automatically' option, then yes, ther would be no need for custom coding.

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem now. You might want to add this to your question

Answer (score 0):

For items connected by USB, it does keep the connection information.  Once you use the Bluetooth Configuration screen and select the devices, do they appear on the MIDI Studio screen.  You may have to create a new External Device.

I think it's like using a new printer.  You have to add the new printer using manual methods.  However, you can print to it using code.

I have an Objective-C program in the BRossTools directory of the GitHub repository https://github.com/BradleyRoss/ObjectiveC-Examples .  If you run the program, it might be interesting to see what happens when you use "Show Configuration" and "Show Sources/Destinations"